# add multiple components to html.Div in loop

Tags: python, checkbox, callback, plotly-dash, rangeslider

I am trying to show some rangesliders depening on the boxes I check in the sliders. The amount of boxes is variable (in the current code some dummy variables) so I think I'll have to add the rangeslider in some sort of callback loop. The way I am doing it now only shows one rangeslider. See the code below.

[code pt1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oBwP9.png)

[code pt2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4iOgw.png)

Hope you guys can help me out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed by adding them to a list and returning that list:
[lst image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ntepg.png)

If someone has a possible better solution I am glad to hear.